# How to create a responsive H3 text

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

How to create a responsive heading with the device viewport width. 
Here is the link to the page where I want to add responsively text heading.
[Link to page](http://home.india-market.online/)

PS. I want to make "INDIA" in background responsive.

[Image of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e77E2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **viewport width** unit to style the font size only if the width of  screen is less than 1024px.

This will ensure that the font size remains `332px` on large screens and will scale properly on smaller devices with width of the screen less than 1024px

```
.wellcome-heading > h3 {
    font-size: 332px;
}

@media(max-width:1023px)
{
 .wellcome-heading > h3 {
    font-size: 30vw;
 }
}
```

Comment: it did nothing. :(

Comment: @Manisha, wat output are u getting?

Comment: I checked ur stylesheet, On line 215 & 230, you already have set styles for h3.

Comment: Either remove them or give unique class name for h3

Comment: Thanks mate! I helped me a lot.
I was editing style.css instead of responsive.css

Answer (score 0):

You can use vw for it's font-size in the CSS.

VW means "viewport width".

Basically, viewport is the size of the browser window. So that would make 1vw equal to 1% of the viewport width.

So, you would change it's font-size in the css to be something like:

```
.wellcome-heading > h2 {
  font-size: 12vw;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vw` or `vh` in your css:

```
h3 {
  font-size: 5vw;
}
```

> vw unit - Equal to 1% of the width of the initial containing block.
>
> vh unit - Equal to 1% of the height of the initial containing block.

See also:

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/imdd_/amrskpe6/

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<h3>Another title</h3>

body {
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 10vh;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 10vw;
}
```

You can use vw as the font-size for resposive font sizing based on the users width, and vh for the height.

Sorry if it doesn't make much sense, first answer here. Easier to check out the fiddle.